# Avoiding Static class

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a public class and then to use it, from two different forms.

Example

```
public class ExtrasAllClasses
{
    public class buttons
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal CustomQuantity { get; set; }

    }

}
```

But when i use the class from both of my forms it creates in using statement static class

Example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WirelessOrdering.Class.MenuClass;
using static WirelessOrdering.Class.AllClasses.ExtrasAllClasses;

namespace WirelessOrdering
{
    public partial class ExtrasForm2 : Form
    {
        public ExtrasForm2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


         public List<buttons> mButtons = new List<buttons>();
```

Is this right?

```
 using static WirelessOrdering.Class.AllClasses.ExtrasAllClasses;
```

Creatin a static class for populating my objects? Is there any other method?

Comment: But i can't access in my form initilization, if i will not set it to static

Comment: Are you asking how to use this?

Comment: The "other method" would be qualifying the name... `List<ExtrasAllClasses.buttons>`

Comment: "Creatin a static class for populating my objects" that's *not at all* what's happening by that line. You should really read the documentation

Comment: He follows up with "Is there any method?" which means that's not really what he is looking for, I think you've tunnel visioned on a single sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage,

```
using WirelessOrdering.Class.AllClasses;

public List<ExtrasAllClasses.buttons> mButtons = 
                                         new List<ExtrasAllClasses.buttons>();
```

To access and instantiate a nested class or any other nested type you have to qualify the name with the outer class

Comment: This doesn't answer the most important part of the question

Comment: The header says "avoiding static class" so I assumed (correctly might I add) that the requirement was to access the nested class without using `using static`.